# Merging two files into one based on the first column

Tags: perl, bash, shell, awk

I have two files, both in the same format -- two columns both containing a number, for example:

**file 1**

```
1.00    99
2.00    343
3.00    34
...
10.00   343
```

**file 2**

```
1.00    0.4
2.00    0.5
3.00    0.34
...
10.00   0.9
```

and i want to generate  the following file (using, awk, bash perl):

```
1.00    99      0.4 
2.00    343     0.5      
3.00    34      0.34
...
10.00   343     0.9
```

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
join file1 file2
```

Which assumes that the files are sorted on the join field. If they are not, you can do this:

```
join <(sort -V file1) <(sort -V file2)
```

Here's an AWK version (the `sort` compensates for AWK's non-deterministic array ordering):

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] FS $2} END {for (i in a) print i a[i]}' file1 file2 | sort -V
```

It seems shorter and more readable than the Perl answer.

In `gawk` 4, you can set the array traversal order:

```
awk 'BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"} {a[$1]=a[$1] FS $2} END {for (i in a) print i a[i]}' file1 file2
```

and you won't have to use the `sort` utility. `@ind_num_asc` is Index Numeric Ascending. See [Controlling Array Traversal and Array Sorting](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Array-Sorting) and [Using Predefined Array Scanning Orders with gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning).

Note that `-V` (`--version-sort`) in the `sort` commands above requires GNU `sort` from coreutils 7.0 or later. Thanks for @simlev pointing out that it should be used if available.

Comment: Only on *nix systems with GNU coreutils installed, AFAIK.

Comment: @Jim: `join` has been part of the default install on every Unix-like system I've ever used. Also "core" means "core". And, based on the OP's tags, I'm assuming a Linux/Unix system.

Comment: @Jim: join is specified by POSIX, and [existed long before](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=join&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Unix+Seventh+Edition&format=html).

Comment: Use `sort -V` for natural order sorting: otherwise `10.00   343     0.9` would come before `1.00    99      0.4`.

Comment: @simlev: Thanks, I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A Perl-solution

```
perl -anE 'push @{$h{$F[0]}}, $F[1]; END{ say "$_\t$h{$_}->[0]\t$h{$_}->[1]" for sort{$a<=>$b} keys %h }' file_1 file_2 > file_3
```

Ok, looking at the awk-oneliner this is shorter then my first try and it has the nicer output then the awk-oneliner and it doesn't use the 'pipe sort -n':

```
perl -anE '$h{$F[0]}="$h{$F[0]}\t$F[1]"; END{say "$_$h{$_}" for sort {$a<=>$b} keys %h}' file_1 file_2
```

And the one-liners behave different then the join-example if there are entries with no value in the second column in the first file.

Comment: I'd use `.=` as it's shorter and clearer. Additionally, I'd avoid `say` as it does not provide any benefit over `print` here. `perl -lane '$h{$F[0]}.="\t$F[1]"; END{print "$_$h{$_}" for sort {$a<=>$b} keys %h}' file_1 file_2`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Alacon - command-line utility for [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) database.

It works with Node.js, so you need to install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and then [Alasql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alasql) package:

To join two data from tab-separated files you can use the following command:

```
> node alacon "SELECT * INTO TSV("main.txt") FROM TSV('data1.txt') data1 
                   JOIN TSV('data2.txt') data2 USING [0]"
```

This is one very long line. In this example all files have data in "Sheet1" sheets.

Comment: DISCLAIMER: you're the developer of Alasql