# Inner join two files based on one column in unix when row names don't match with sort

Tags: python, r, unix, awk

I'm running into an issue trying to join two datasets in unix and could use your help. I've spent a long time searching the forum for a solution but turned up empty handed.

I have a list of accession numbers in one dataset and need to convert these to gene symbols. In order to do so I downloaded the gene2accession.gz [from NCBI](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/DATA/). The uncompressed file is ~7Gb so first I cut out the accession and gene symbol from this dataset

```
cut -f 2,16 gene2accession > accession2genesymbol
```

There are ~70 million lines as per `wc -l accession2genesymbol` with many duplicates so I removed these with `sort accession2genesymbol | uniq` which resulted in ~20 million lines.

Now normally I would do an [`inner_join()` using the `dplyr` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf) in R (return all rows from x where there are matching values in y, and all columns from x and y); however, this dataset is far too large for me to work with.

Here is a sample of the *unsorted* accession2genesymbol dataset:

```
100000492       mafaa
1000004 XCC3444
110047139       LOC110047139
110047140       LOC110047140
9951915         LOAG_14435
9951916         LOAG_14436
999999          gndA
999             CDH1
9               NAT1
```

A short example of the unsorted the Accessions looks like this (for the whole dataset -1,576 lines [see the gist](https://gist.github.com/moldach/277fff8f2b4633fd3a6c04faf6b72a20)):

```
Accessions
10047140
100913206
10092617
10190704
10190704
103471987
103471997
103472005
103472005
105990514
45006951
45006986
45006986
45007007
45007007
4501883
4501887
94721250
94721261
9558733
9845516
98986457
98986457
98986464
99028871
9910242
9951915
9966805
9966827
9966867
9994185
```

**EDIT: Only accession 9951915 and 110047140 here have matches so my expected output would be:**

```
9951915         LOAG_14435
110047140       LOC110047140
```

Not having worked with unix much for data manipulation/joining I searched Stack Overflow for similar problems.

For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072180/merging-two-files-into-one-based-on-the-first-column). It's my understanding that unix `join` function can only be used if the files are sorted so I tried the following:

```
join -t "\t" <(dos2unix <accession) <(dos2unix <accession2genesymbol.txt)
```

Perhaps this is not working because I would need ***exactly*** the same row numbers in both datasets (i.e. if row 100 of dataset doesn't match row 100 of dataset2 it wont work) but perhaps I'm wrong and this didn't work for some other reason?

Perhaps `awk` is a better solution, so I tried a suggestion from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072180/merging-two-files-into-one-based-on-the-first-column):

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] FS $2} END {for (i in a) print i a[i]}' accession accession2genesymbol | sort > file3
```

This produces a file with ~20 million lines and since my accession is only 9000 lines I would expect 9000 (or potentially fewer if those accessions no longer exist, for example).

I tried another `awk` solution from the first post:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print $2}' accession accession2genesymbol > file3
awk: warning: escape sequence `\+' treated as plain `+'
```

But I end up with an empty file.

I'd appreciate an awk(ward) solution, python, or whatever would help me solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: 7gb is not all _that_ big -- you should get more RAM (perhaps deploying to a cloud instance like GCP or AWS) and/or use `data.table`. if you really want a low-memoet solution, this looks like a perfect problem for a `MapReduce`- or `spark`-based solution.

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given your 2 input files. It's not clear how you'd get any output at all given those 2 samples.

Comment: You could use a very rudimentary approach of `split`ting files and joining piece by piece, that fit into memory.

Comment: @EdMorton I've now edited the question to include a better reproducible example with expected output. These have the headers already removed and have been sorted with `sort`

Comment: Put it back to it's original uncut, unsorted state with the headers included and get rid of the `...` lines - if we need to select fields or sort it and remove a header we can easily do that,  we just need something we can test with. Just give us 2 files of 10 or less lines each and some overlap between the data in the 2 files so there should be some output. You've told us how large your `gene2accession` file is - also tell us how large your `Accessions` file is.

Comment: OK i put the original uncut, unsorted `Accession` file with the header into a gist - it's 1567 lines (not big at all) https://gist.github.com/moldach/277fff8f2b4633fd3a6c04faf6b72a20. The `gene2accession` file is 7 GB and can be downloaded from the NCBI link I provided. I used `cut -f2,16` to to get this into `accession2genesymbol` before trying `join <(sed 1d Acession) <(sort -n accession2genesymbol)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We haven't seen a sample of your original `gene2accession` file yet but let's assume it's a tab-separated field with `accession` in the 2nd column and `gene` in the 16th (since that's what your `cut` is selecting) with a header line. Let's also assume that your `Accessions` file isn't absolutely enormous.

Given that, this script should do what you want:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} ($2 in a) && !seen[$2]++{print $2, $16}' Accessions gene2accession
```

but you could try this to see if it's faster:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $2 in a{print $2, $16}' Accessions <(sort -u -t'\t' -k2,2 gene2accession)
```

and if it is and you want an intermediate file for the output of the `sort` to use in subsequent runs:

```
sort -u -t'\t' -k2,2 gene2accession > unq_gene2accession &&
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $2 in a{print $2, $16}' Accessions unq_gene2accession
```

Comment: So I've tried your first example here with the `Accessions` which can be found at the gist and the `gene2accession` file directly from NCBI. I get an error `awk: warning: escape sequence '\+' treated as plain '+'` and no output.

The second example ("try this to see if it's faster") produces the same error as well as another one `sort: multi-character tab '\\t'`.

Could this be caused by carriage return from the NCBI file? I downloaded it directly to linux; however, maybe whomever loaded that file to NCBI did so from windows?

Comment: You said you were getting that error before - to be clear neither the script you originally had nor this one will produce that error message since neither contains `\+` so you are executing some other script that we don't know about. Change `\t` to `$'\t'` in the call to `sort` or just get rid of it if there's no other spaces in your file.

Comment: I changed `\t` to `$'\t'` like so: `awk -F$'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $2 in a{print $2, $16}' Accessions <(sort -u -t$'\t' -k2,2 gene2accession) > output` but I don't get any output.

When I ran `file Accessions` I found it had CRLF line terminators. Running `dos2unix Accessions` and then sorting both files followed by `grep -h -w -f Accessions accession2genesymbol > output` seems to produce the desired output (269 lines long).

Now re-running your command `awk -F$'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $2 in a{print $2, $16}' Accessions <(sort -u -t$'\t' -k2,2 gene2accession) > output` gives same result

Comment: Seems to be the case of frustrating DOS line endings. Wish I would have checked this much earlier but glad I know the problem know and will be using `file` as a sanity check much more often now. Thanks @edmorton for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

`join` should work for your case. since your input files don't have matches here is a made up example and using your map file

```
$ head file
100000009
100000061
100000030

$ join <(sed 1d map) <(sort file)
100000009 sema5bb+
100000030 btr24+
100000061 si:ch211-133n4.9+
```

assuming your `map` file is already sorted, you need to remove the header `sed 1d` and need to sort your input `file`.  Note that sorting should be both numerical or lexical.

Another alternative, which doesn't require sorting is with `grep`

```
$ grep -wFf file map
100000009       sema5bb+
100000030       btr24+
100000061       si:ch211-133n4.9+
```

if the numbers and codes are not in the same format there won't be false matches.

Comment: Neither of these examples work on the data. I edited my post to update data and expected output; I manually removed the headers of each file with `sed 1d` and then sorted with `sort` to show what the datasets look like. Perhaps something weird with the sort is going on because if you look at the tail section of accession2gene it goes from 999999 to 999 to 9. Similarly, for the other dataset you see 99028871 and then 9910242 - so it's putting a smaller numbers way later in the sorted dataset because it's looking at the 3rd digit in this case and not actually the length of the number itself.

Comment: That's not weird, you just must've sorted alphabetically instead of numerically (i.e. you didn't add `-n` to the sort command).

Comment: I tried `join <(sed 1d Accession) <(sort -n accession2genesymbol)` with no luck. This is trying on the Accession file I've included with a gist link now (an unsorted file with a header). I get a `join` error saying file 1 and file 2 are not in sorted order.

Comment: `grep -wFf Accessions accession2genesymbol` also works if the file has no CRLF line endings